# Selenium - Script is failing after firefox update

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

Recently Updated firefox 43.0.1. Script started failing. However It works fine in Google Chorme. Following is the error.

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1385

Comment: Please update your `WebDriver` version

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue and i know it has been answered but for future make sure to disable your Firefox auto update feature.